# Nexus 7 won't boot up - could it be due to cell phone sitting on top of it?

Tags: nexus-7, unbricking

I've had my Nexus 7 for about 4 months and it's been working well until about a couple days ago. It ran out of battery so I plugged in the charger. It began charging but something weird happened when it turned on. It started having static lines across the screen and it would work for about 3 min and then the static lines would appear. After that it would turn off.

I left it charging for about 6 hrs and now it won't boot up at all. Could this be due to a cell phone sitting on top of the Nexus 7 cover for a couple days? Could it be that the radio frequency from the cell phone messed up the Nexus 7? I'd appreciate some help getting this booting again.

Answer (score 1):

It could very well be due to your mobile sitting on top of it.

There may have been an electrostatic discharge from your phone, that was sent through the Nexus 7, breaking/harming some components.

If you can, I would suggest you take it to the repair center - it would be the only way if this is what has happened.